# Weird lldb behavior (comparing to gdb) C

Tags: c, macos, debugging, gdb, lldb

I come from freebsd and I'm used to debug with GDB, unfortunately, GDB is not natif on my macbook, I wanted to debug using LLDB.

Unfortunately, I don't understand this weird behavior :

When I launch a C program and I breakpoint on one function, and then I launch it using "run", I go to the breakpoint but then it appears that I can read through but in the assembly code = hard debuging, not like in GDB where it is straight line by line => easy debuging

look at the .c, (I know this code is awful but it's not the point, it's just for trying to set lldb properly)

```
int ft_count_point(char *m, int i)
{
    int count;
    int count_c;

    count = 0;
    count_c = 0;
    while (m[i] != '\0' || (m[i] != '\n' && m[i + 1] != '\n'))
    {
        if (m[i] == '.')
        {
            count_c++;
            count++;
        }
        if (m[i] == '\n' || m[i] == '#')
            count++;
        i++;
    }
    if (count != 20 && count_c != 16)
        return (1);
    exit (0);
}
```

The main function contains only a call on this fonction and return 0.

Look at what I get using lldb with a breakpoint on ft_count_point:

```
(lldb) target create "./a.out"
Current executable set to './a.out' (x86_64).
(lldb) settings set -- target.run-args  "tests/error1"
(lldb) b ft_count_point
Breakpoint 1: where = a.out`ft_count_point + 35
    at ft_count_point.c:5, address = 0x00000001000073e3
(lldb) r
Process 17302 launched: './a.out' (x86_64)
AddressSanitizer debugger support is active. Memory error breakpoint
has been installed and you can now use the 'memory history' command.
Process 17302 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x43c1e7, 0x00007fff5fc01000 dyld`_dyld_start,
                   stop reason = exec
    frame #0: 0x00007fff5fc01000 dyld`_dyld_start
dyld`_dyld_start:
->  0x7fff5fc01000 <+0>: popq   %rdi
    0x7fff5fc01001 <+1>: pushq  $0x0
    0x7fff5fc01003 <+3>: movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x7fff5fc01006 <+6>: andq   $-0x10, %rsp
```

I can go step by step into this but seriously, it's a waste of time.

Comment: Do you have symbolic debugging information enabled in the executable?

Comment: I don't know, does it has something to do with my ~/.lldbinit config file ?

Comment: You do have debug information.  You can tell because lldb found a file & line number for your breakpoint.  If you didn't have debug info it would only be an address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your program re-exec's itself - maybe this is actually something that ASAN is doing for you?  You can see this in the lldb output, where it says:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x43c1e7, 0x00007fff5fc01000 dyld`_dyld_start,
                   stop reason = exec
```

If you had actually hit your breakpoint, the reason would be `stop reason = breakpoint 1.1` or whatever breakpoint number was appropriate.

In lldb, we stop on re-exec, my guess is gdb auto-continues after an exec, which is why you didn't notice this in gdb.  You should be able to continue, and you will hit your real breakpoint in a bit.

Might be a good idea to have a setting to control whether to continue past exec or not.  Feel free to file a bug with the lldb.llvm.org bug reporter.

Comment: I see this when debugging arducopter on macOS. Is there now an option to prevent this? It's driving me mad!

Comment: Ahh I see that https://stackoverflow.com/a/57065760/5325222 has the answer