# How to fix lldb stopping immediately after run call?

Tags: macos, lldb, macos-mojave

I'm using lldb on Mojave with Xcode 10.2.1. As soon as command 'run' to lldb, this happens:

```
(lldb) target create "<executable>"
Current executable set to '<executable>' (x86_64).
(lldb) run
Process 95857 launched: '/Users/<path to executable>' (x86_64)
Process 95857 stopped
* thread #2, stop reason = exec
    frame #0: 0x0000000102491000 dyld`_dyld_start
dyld`_dyld_start:
->  0x102491000 <+0>: popq   %rdi
    0x102491001 <+1>: pushq  $0x0
    0x102491003 <+3>: movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x102491006 <+6>: andq   $-0x10, %rsp
Target 0: (pmtad) stopped.
```

I've tried looking up issue relating to the dyld`_dyld_start print-out, as that's the only lead I could come up with. I read that this might be something having to do with trying to re-run the executable, though I wasn't very sure what was being described.

I should just be able to run this fine. It works on other machines with older OS's.

Answer (score 9):

The program you are running exec'ed another (or the same) binary.  That's the meaning of the "stop reason = exec" message.  By default, lldb stops when a program re-exec's itself, but if you want it not to, then do:

```
(lldb) settings set target.process.stop-on-exec false
```

You can also put this in your ~/.lldbinit.

Comment: Is there anything I should be worried about in terms of overriding this feature?

Comment: The only thing this turns off is the notification that the program you were debugging has exec'ed itself for some reason or other.  The program itself will behave exactly the same under lldb with and without this setting.  Whether to set it on or off is just a trade-off between being able to see when a program calls exec, and having to "continue" after being told so.